# ViewPager swipe issue when back press

Tags: android, android-viewpager

here am trying to move to the next screen at view pager last position..and its moving .but when i try to swipe back from the last position ,it moves to the next screen.i need to move to the next screeen only when view pager at last position.

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {       
  //viewpager swipe
  lastPageChange = false;
  int lastIdx = viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1;
  curItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
  if (curItem==lastIdx && state==1 && lastPageChange==false ) {
    lastPageChange = true;
    Intent main=new Intent(Top3.this,SkipActivity.class);
    startActivity(main);
    finish();
  } else {
    lastPageChange = false;
  }    
}
```

Comment: The **lastPageChange==false** part in your **if** statement is always TRUE. You assign **false** to **lastPageChange** at the beginning of the function and the check in the if statement is useless.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is Your viewpager when you seen last position then swipe again forward it will go to next Activity.
 ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pagerListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                    boolean lastPageChange = false;

```
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    int lastIdx = book_adapt.getCount() - 1;

                    Log.d("Testing", "pos:" + position);
                    if (lastPageChange && position == lastIdx){
                        Intent main = new Intent(Top3.this, SkipActivity.class);
                        startActivity(main);
                        finish();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // pgText.setCurrentItem(i/2);
                    viewPagerSet(position);
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                    int lastIdx = book_adapt.getCount() - 1;

                    int curItem = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                    if (curItem == lastIdx /*&& lastPos==lastIdx*/ && state == 1)
                        lastPageChange = true;
                    else lastPageChange = false;
                }
            };

            viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(pagerListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try no to remove 1 from the **viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()**

I suppose the following thing is happening - lets say you have 5 tabs in your **viewPager**. You are at the last tab. You swipe back and **viewPager.getCurrentItem()** will return 4. At the same time you have **viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1** which will return 4 again (5 tabs - 1). And the condition in your **if** statement will be always **True**, thus the new activity will be loaded.